# How to implement deadLetterQueue for JDBC Connector Using Until Successful

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I am trying implement deadLetterQueue on UntilSuccessful for JDBC Connector. I would like to send the payload to a queue(DeadLetterQueue) when UntilSuccessful fails after trying no of times as configured. I referred following links

http://blogs.mulesoft.org/meet-until-successful-store-and-forward-for-mule/

[Where in the application would you define the vm:endpoint for a dlqEndpoint-ref defined in an until-successful scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18775121/where-in-the-application-would-you-define-the-vmendpoint-for-a-dlqendpoint-ref)

Below is my code snippet

```
<vm:endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" path="dlqChannel" name="VM" doc:name="VM"/>
```

Above line is my global element

```
<flow...>  .... <until-successful objectStore-ref="objectStore" deadLetterQueue-ref="dlqChannel" maxRetries="5" secondsBetweenRetries="60" doc:name="Until Successful" failureExpression="exception-type:java.sql.SQLException">
                  <jdbc-ee:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" queryKey="Insert Query" queryTimeout="-1" connector-ref="Database" doc:name="Database"/>
    </until-successful>....</flow>

<flow name="Flow2" doc:name="Flow2">
    <endpoint ref="dlqChannel" />
    <logger message="DEAD DEAD DEAD LETTER LETTER LETTER #[message]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
</flow>
```

At this line `<endpoint ref="dlqChannel" />` I am getting compile error says "Reference to unknown global element:dlqChannel"

Can any one suggest a best way to achieve this scenario.

Thanks,
Kalyan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is resolved.

Below is my code snippet.

```
<vm:endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" path="dlq" name="dlqChannel" doc:name="VM"/>
```

Above line is vm global element

```
<flow...> ...  <until-successful objectStore-ref="objectStore" deadLetterQueue-ref="dlqChannel" maxRetries="2" secondsBetweenRetries="10" doc:name="Until Successful" failureExpression="exception-type:java.sql.SQLException">
                  <jdbc-ee:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" queryKey="Insert Query" queryTimeout="-1" connector-ref="Database" doc:name="Database"/>
    </until-successful>

....
</flow>

<flow name="Flow2" doc:name="Flow2">
    <vm:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" path="dlq" doc:name="VM"/>
    <logger message="DEAD DEAD DEAD LETTER LETTER LETTER #[message.payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
</flow>
```

Based on "deadLetterQueue-ref" in UntilSuccessful, payload goes to vm:inbound-endpoint(vm://dlq) as defined in the vm global endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

Your endpoint is called 'VM' not 'dlqChannel'. Change either the name to dlqChannel or point it to VM.

Comment: Definitely rename the vm:endpoint to dlqChannel.  A VM endpoint named VM tells noone anything.

Answer (score 0):

As Seba correctly points out, your error is due to a wrong name/ref. As for how to implement the deadLetterQueue, you need an inbound endpoint. So in Flow2, change the endpoint to `<inbound-endpoint ref="dlqChannel" />`.